# Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth headphone pairs but audio plays through laptop speakers

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I'm very new to Ubuntu so I'm sorry if my question sounds dumb. I have Edifier tws1 headphones and I'm trying to get them to work on my laptop. At first they connected like expected but when i tried to play something the audio was super choppy, would lag, etc.

I looked around online and people suggested installing blueman, which I did. Now the headphone will pair and it says it's connected but the sound will continue playing through the laptop speakers, as if nothing was connected. Here is a screenshot, so you guys can see the situation:

[image: screenshot]